# Delete a specific block in yaml file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, yaml

Need to delete booking block from below yml file

```
testing:
     working:
       - aaa: daa
       - bbb: rrr
     booking:
       empty_book:
         test_list:
           - ccc: tt
           - ddd: ttt
     maintaining:
       - eee: dhhaa
       - fff: ffdaa
```

tried with sed and and awk command to delete booking block but not got expected result as below.

looking for below output

```
testing:
     working:
       - aaa: daa
       - bbb: rrr
     maintaining:
       - eee: dhhaa
       - fff: ffdaa
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried and describe what it did instead of the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) tool for processing YAML files – it is specifically built for this job:

```
$ yq 'del(.testing.booking)' file.yml
testing:
  working:
    - aaa: daa
    - bbb: rrr
  maintaining:
    - eee: dhhaa
    - fff: ffdaa
```

To update a file inplace (unrecoverably overwriting the original!), run `yq -i …`.

Comment: yq tool will support find and grep commands ? I need to delete same block in multiple yml files ?

Is this command will work in yq tool ?:- 
find . -type f -name "*.yml" -print0 | xargs -0 yq 'del(.testing.booking)'


One more question is that not possible to achive with bash script ? using sed/awk/find commands ?

Comment: @sachinbm you can use `yq` in a bash script, just like you would use sed/awk/find/xargs in a bash script: all of them are simply external commands that are called by your shell. And yes, `yq` should be able to handle multiple paths (when invoked with xargs) – if it doesn't, run `xargs -n1` to invoke yq with a single argument only

Comment: @sachinbm I'm sure it's possible to develop a fragile and brittle solution using sed and awk, but why would you want to do that when a tool specfically for handling yaml exists? How will your sed/awk solution handle inputs such as `{"testing":{"working":[{"aaa":"daa"},{"bbb":"rrr"}],"maintaining":[{"eee":"dhhaa"},{"fff":"ffdaa"}]}` (still valid yaml and yq will handle that perfectly)